# redis.lpush a number of items

Tags: node.js, node-redis

In my `node.js` script I have an array of strings, and I want to `LPUSH` these strings into a Redis queue. I tried:

```
var redis = require('redis').createClient();
redis.lpush('queue', ['1', '2', '3'])
```

which results in a single string being pushed:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> lrange queue 0 -1
1) "1,2,3"
```

Redis supports multiple values in `LPUSH` command, I am looking for help on utilizing this functionality. I am not asking how to loop over my array and push each item separately. :)

EDIT:

I know if I do this:

```
redis.lpush('queue', '1', '2', '3')
```

I get what I expect, but in my real application the array is generated at run time, and I do not know its contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue/common request](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/issues/422)

One of the suggested workarounds is to use [send_command directly](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/issues/369#issuecomment-13050944)

You might also try this (haven't tried this myself):

```
myvalues.unshift('queue');
redis.lpush.apply(redis, myvalues);
```

Comment: thanks. both `send_command` and `apply` work, except for `unshift` returns the new length, so I had to do it as a separate statement.

Comment: >= 2.4: Accepts multiple value arguments. In Redis versions older than 2.4 it was possible to push a single value per command. [doc](http://redis.io/commands/lpush)

Answer (score 25):

This is now possible with [es6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). An array of any size will be spread out as the arguments to the function.

```
redis.lpush('queue', ...arrayOfValues)
```

Comment: You don't even need to use spread syntax anymore. Just passing an array will suffice. P.S. This answer is more up to date than the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the correct answer rather than the accepted one.